# iphone 4s doesn't call the RegisterPass Request after Coupon pass is added to passbook

Tags: ios, iphone, passbook

iphone 4s (running ios 8.3) doesn't call the RegisterPass Request after Coupon pass is added to passbook.

pass book can be found at 
http://home.shortkut.co/api/public/PassbookCoupon2/1054

When add my pass to the passbook on my iphone 4s device, I only see...
in my logs I only see. 
GET /api/public/PassbookCoupon2/1054 --- 200 OK

And not the subsequent register message.

However, on iphone 5s, I see
GET /api/public/PassbookCoupon2/1054 --- 200 OK

POST /api/v1/devices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/registrations/pass.co.shortkut.home/01927847623423234234 --- 200 OK

GET /api/v1/devices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/registrations/pass.co.shortkut.home --- 200 OK

Do i need to anythign special for iphone 4s

Comment: Are both devices on the same network (ie. same WiFi)? Might have something to do with the POST request being on HTTPS.

Comment: Post being on HTTPS?
No, both devices are on different network,.

Comment: Passbook webservice needs to be served through HTTPS. The only way to use unencrypted connections is using a development device and enabling a setting in the Developer section of iOS. So concerning your issue, either your webservice is HTTP and one of your device is in dev mode, or your webservice is HTTPS and one of your device might refuse the connection (prolly network issue)

Comment: Which one? You should explain how you fixed the issue for others.

Comment: We had a development device and setting enabled in developer section of ios for the iphone 5, so that worked, but iphone 4 didn't. Once I connected it to my mac got the error.  Resolved it by changing the url to be https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we were using http url for the passbook property, WebServiceUrl and the iphone 5 device was devlopment enabled, but iphone 4 wasn't.

Once we chnaged the WebServiceUrl to be https, it worked across all devices.